# getAttribute('href') always returning '#' regardless of actual href attribute on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile

I have an anchor element

```
<a href="./LayerFilter.html">Markers</a>
```

and its event listener

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
    alert($(e.target).attr('href'));
    alert(e.target.getAttribute('href'));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

both return `./LayerFilter.html` on the desktop, but `#` on the android browsers (tried 2.3 and 3.x)

if I add `data-href='./LayerFilter.html'` to the anchor element and use `$(e.target).attr('data-href')`, Android suddenly gets the correct value.

What's the deal with this?
Is there a way to not have to add a new attribute to anchor and just use the href?

Comment: How about e.target.href? In theory, it should always give the full URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this was due to jquery mobile "enhancing" the page
I was on 1.1.0, upgrading to 1.1.1 solved the problem.